# Ability to disable text input in package "vue-search-select" - "basic-select" component

Tags: vuejs2

I want to disable text input in the "basic-select" component, from the "vue-search-select" package

because there are already ready-made styles for it, and I would not want to create a separate customized select

is it possible? Tell me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no explicit API to disable text input because this package is going to make a "searchable" select component. The [text input](https://github.com/moreta/vue-search-select/blob/master/src/lib/BasicSelect.vue#L9-L26) can be hidden using CSS, however.

```css
.search {
  display: none;
}

/* or even better */
.ui.search.dropdown > input.search {
  display: none;
}
```

However, you should be careful about the selector you choose. Depending on your project, it might have some side effects. It might be better to add a custom class to the component and use it as follows:

```css
.my-custom-class .ui.search.dropdown > input.search {
  display: none;
}
```